# Link2SD is showing "mount: operation not permitted"

Tags: sony-xperia, link2sd

I have rooted my Sony Xperia M2 Dual (D2302) using *KingRoot* and it currently has Sony stock firmware (android 5.1.1, build: 18.6.A.0.182) with locked bootloader. I have checked the root availability using Rootchecker app from play store. To link the apps to micro SD card Link2SD app has been installed from play store. A *16 GB class 10 micro SD* card has been used to provide the second partition. The partitions I have tried (using *Minitool*) are-

- 8 GB FAT32 + 6.8 GB EXT2
- 8 GB FAT32 + 6.8 GB EXT4
- 8 GB FAT32 + 6.8 GB FAT32

In each and every case when Link2SD is launched, selecting ext2/ext4/fat32 shows "**Mount script cannot be created. mount: Operation not permitted**" error. I have rebooted the phone several times, checked root permission again and also tried to "su" from terminal and there were no error. In the Link2SD *storage info* the second partition is shown as *"not mounted"* partition. Why this error is being occurred? What should be the solution to this problem? Is it possible to solve the problem by running custom mount script?

Comment: i have the same problem, i have installed an app, then i make it as a system app and now i cant make it a user app again, shows me that error message: "mount: operation no permitted" did you fix it?

Comment: Yeah, I have fixed it. The KingRoot didn't actually root the phone with all of the r/w permissions at /boot and /system. So, I have unrooted the phone and rooted again with **EagleRoot** and got full access to the /system and /boot directory. So that, Link2SD didn't show this error anymore. To root using Eagleroot you can follow this link (https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-m2/general/eagleroottool-t3390663)